# Django rest framework csv renderer doesn't render €(EUR) sign correctly

Tags: python, django, csv, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-framework-csv(https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv/) to download csv from api.

Problem is when I write row with `€` sign, I get it like this in excel:
[image]

Code:

```py
renderer = CSVRenderer()

renderer.header = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'nutrition_text', 'monthly_total_price']
renderer.labels = {
    'last_name': 'Nachname', 
    'first_name': 'Vorname', 
    'nutrition_text': 'Ernährung', 
    'monthly_total_price': 'Monthly total price'
}
data = [
    {'last_name': 'asdasd', 'first_name': 'asdas', 'nutrition_text': '', 'monthly_total_price': ''}, 
    {'last_name': 'Delic', 'first_name': 'Mirza', 'nutrition_text': '', 'monthly_total_price': '-18.00€'}
]

response = HttpResponse(renderer.render(data), content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Data.csv"'

return response
```

Excel screenshot:

[image]

Also, `Ernährung` is not good in excel.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into [CSVRenderer](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv/blob/58c818866b83ec10681254fe1486dc5bd958f17b/rest_framework_csv/renderers.py#L21), the encoding used in the csv buffer is the default in django.conf. In [django.conf:DEFAULT_CHARSET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#default-charset) we can see this encoding is UTF-8.

If the string you are flushing to the csv is not encoded in utf-8 you can have such output. So maybe you should encode your data before passing it off to `renderer.redner(data)` using [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes) first.

Comment: Yeah, and how does it show later in Excel? Also did you try other encodings, such as `'windows-1251'` or `'iso-8859-1'`? Plus, something might be happening in Excel as such (it is dependant on system regional settings on your machine). You should first check what characters does the actual plain csv file has to verify that it is CSVRender not working and not Excel messing up your csv.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the characters are getting encoded (by CSVRenderer) as UTF-8 but decoded (by Excel) as plain ASCII.  Try this method to [open CSV files that are UTF-8 encoded in Excel](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-display-csv-files-with-unicode-utf-8-encoding-in-excel):

1. Go to the Data ribbon menu > From Text
2. In the import wizard, specify File data type: Delimited (by Comma) and File Origin: Unicode (UTF-8)